# Java charAt() String index out of range: 0

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
private void submitPstart() {

    if (tStock.getText().charAt(0)>='A' && tStock.getText().charAt(0)<='Z'){


    }else {
        errorBox ("Uppercase A-Z");
    }

    tStock.setText("");
    tStock.setFocus();
}
```

THis is working but when I try not to put anything on the textbox and press the OK button it crashes. It says:

`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`

and it pointed out to this part: `if (tStock.getText().charAt(0)>='A' && tStock.getText().charAt(0)<='Z')`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must check null and length greater than 0.

```
 if (tStockPIStart!=null && tStockPIStart.getText().length()>0 && tStockPIStart.getText().charAt(0)>='A' && tStockPIStart.getText().charAt(0)<='Z'){
```

Comment: what if sir for example I enter a lower case letter and want it to conver to upper case?

Comment: you can do two thing 1. add lower case condition or 2. use equalsignorecase.

Comment: `if (tStockPIStart!=null && tStockPIStart.getText().length()>0 && "A".equalsIgnoreCase(""+tStockPIStart.getText().charAt(0)) && "Z".equalsIgnoreCase(""+tStockPIStart.getText().charAt(0))){}`

Comment: I think it would make life easier if tStockPIStart.getText() was extracted into a variable

Answer (score 7):

You need to check if `getText()` returns a 0-length (i.e. empty) string.

If it does, then don't try to pull the first character out! (via `charAt()`)

Note that your commented-out check for `length()` should occur *prior* to the existing character check.

You may want to check for a null string being returned as well, depending on your framework/solution etc. Note the [Apache Commons StringUtils.isEmpty()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) method, which performs this check concisely.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (tStockPIStart.getText().length() > 0 && tStockPIStart.getText().charAt(0)>='A' && tStockPIStart.getText().charAt(0)<='Z')
```

In your case, if the text is empty, then the length returned will be 0. Hence the charAt(..) method will throw you an exception. As such, you should first check that the text that you're trying to compare is empty or not.

Comment: thanks for this sir. i also tried this one and its working :)

Comment: what if sir for example I enter a lower case letter and want it to conver to upper case?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
if (tStockPIStart!=null && tStockPIStart.length>0) {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 there is the [isEmpty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) method you can use to make things a bit more expressive in your code

```
if (tStockPIStart.getText()!=null && !tStockPIStart.getText().isEmpty()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

This is the same as doing `length != 0` but I personally think is a bit more clear.